# Hibernate @NotEmpty is deprecated

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using [5.2.13.Final](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.13.Final) version of [hibernate-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core) and 
5.2.13.Final version of [hibernate-validator](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator).

```
@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "SSO_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String ssoId;
```

`@NotEmpty` comes in picture when I need the following validation message from the`message.properties` file when `ssoId` is empty:

`NotEmpty.user.ssoId=SSO ID can not be blank.`

But `@NotEmpty` is deprecated in the latest version. What is its equivalent?

Comment: Try to use `javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty` instead (cf. https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotEmpty.java) .

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Generally, as something is marked as deprecated in a javadoc, the javadoc explains also what is the alternative to.

The [**org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty annotation javadoc**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/6.0/api/index.html?org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotEmpty.html) states (emphasis is mine) :

> **Deprecated**. use the **standard javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty** constraint instead

Note that since Hibernate **5**, Hibernate deprecated several of its specific validation constraint classes in favor to standard [JSR 380-bean validation](http://beanvalidation.org/2.0/) classes.
Note also that the Hibernate Validator **6** library is actually [the reference implementation of this JSR](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/).

[Here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/index.html?deprecated-list.html) is an updated list of deprecated API for Hibernate validator.

Comment: that means we have to use both kind of annotations, Hibernate and javaannotations together?

Comment: Not "have to" but you may if you use specific Hibernate validation annotations that don't have counterparts in the JSR.  If you use Hibernate Validator 6, it should not be a problem as it is the default implementation of the JSR. So you would have only `javax.validation` annotations.

Answer (score 15):

Use
`import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;`
instead of
`import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;`

Comment: Can you please elaborate with a working answer? Where does "NotBlank" go? Is it also an attribute (@NotBlank) ?