# Spring Data Test ExpectedException - No exception thrown

Tags: java, spring, testing, exception, junit

I've been creating a few tests into `my studing project, but the ExpectedException is not working as expected. I'm doing a simple saving without the name (which should throw an exception) and it's not throwing anything.

OBS:

1. When I change spring-boot-starter-parent from "2.1.12.RELEASE" to 
   "1.5.4.RELEASE" it works. But I really want to understand why.
2. I already tried Using NotEmpty from "javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty"

Thanks!

------------ Student.java ------------

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
public class Student extends AbstractEntity{

public Student() {
}

public Student(String name, String email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
}

@NotEmpty(message = "O campo nome do estudante é obrigatório")
private String name;

@NotEmpty
@Email
//    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(255) default 'John Snow'")
    private String email;
```

------------ StudentRepository.java ------------

```
import br.com.devdojo.awesome.model.Student;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

public interface StudentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Student, Long> {
    List<Student> findByNameIgnoreCaseContaining(String name);
}
```

------------ StudentRepositoryTest.java ------------

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class StudentRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void createWhenNameIsNullShouldThrownConstraintViolationException() {
        thrown.expect(ConstraintViolationException.class);
        thrown.expectMessage("O campo nome do estudante é obrigatório");
        this.studentRepository.save(new Student());
    }
```

------------ POM FILE ------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>Projects</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.12.RELEASE</version>
</parent>




<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:/sqldeveloper/jdbc/lib/ojdbc8.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <version>8.0.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

------------ ERROR MESSAGE ------------

```
2020-02-24 15:16:01.788  INFO 16196 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.15.Final}
2020-02-24 15:16:01.790  INFO 16196 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2020-02-24 15:16:01.997  INFO 16196 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2020-02-24 15:16:02.216  INFO 16196 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
Hibernate: create table spring_user (id bigint not null, admin boolean not null, name varchar(255) not null, password varchar(255) not null, user_name varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table student (id bigint not null, email varchar(255), name varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table spring_user drop constraint if exists UK_6p8pvty87x0ovxe0v5ght3l3r
Hibernate: alter table spring_user add constraint UK_6p8pvty87x0ovxe0v5ght3l3r unique (user_name)
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
2020-02-24 15:16:03.166  INFO 16196 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-02-24 15:16:03.721  INFO 16196 --- [           main] b.c.d.awesome.StudentRepositoryTest      : Started StudentRepositoryTest in 5.05 seconds (JVM running for 6.214)
2020-02-24 15:16:03.745  INFO 16196 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@25ce9dc4 testClass = StudentRepositoryTest, testInstance = br.com.devdojo.awesome.StudentRepositoryTest@742ff096, testMethod = createWhenEmailIsNullShouldThrownConstraintViolationException@StudentRepositoryTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@74ea2410 testClass = StudentRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class br.com.devdojo.awesome.ApplicationStart}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@17f62e33 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@3eb738bb, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@185a6e9, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@49438269, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@36807d48, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@6f4a47c7], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@4e85dcb2]; rollback [true]
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55458', transport: 'socket'
2020-02-24 15:16:38.447  INFO 16196 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@25ce9dc4 testClass = StudentRepositoryTest, testInstance = br.com.devdojo.awesome.StudentRepositoryTest@742ff096, testMethod = createWhenEmailIsNullShouldThrownConstraintViolationException@StudentRepositoryTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@74ea2410 testClass = StudentRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class br.com.devdojo.awesome.ApplicationStart}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@17f62e33 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@3eb738bb, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@185a6e9, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@49438269, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@36807d48, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@6f4a47c7], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]

java.lang.AssertionError: Expected test to throw (an instance of java.lang.IllegalStateException and exception with message a string containing "O campo nome do estudante é obrigatório")

at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.failDueToMissingException(ExpectedException.java:263)
at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.access$200(ExpectedException.java:106)
at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:245)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)

2020-02-24 15:16:38.461  INFO 16196 --- [       Thread-3] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by using `EntityManager#flush` method - this forces synchronization of your managed entities to database. The `save` method does not guarantee synchronization with database will happen immediately and it looks like it also does not guarantee validations will be done immediately. (I've tested with 1.5 version too and the validation is immediate as you have noticed.)

I would recommend using `EntityManager#flush` in your tests anyway: You can miss also some other bugs in your code without it (like inserting two rows with the same unique key).

`EntityManager` can be autowired like any other bean:

```java
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

This behavior is also mentioned in [Hibernate's FAQ](https://hibernate.org/validator/faq/#why-is-my-jpa-entity-not-validated-when-i-call-persist).

Comment: Thank you, Josef! It worked! Can you tell me where I can find out about these version changes that can break my code?

Comment: After a bit of searching around I'm not really sure if the behavior of 1.5 (Hibernate 5.0) was actually correct anyway. As Hibernate FAQ states - calling flush for validation is expected behavior:
https://hibernate.org/validator/faq/#why-is-my-jpa-entity-not-validated-when-i-call-persist
IMHO the best way to go is what you are doing - writing tests and trying to find out how things work and how to do them better. Following version changes for main libraries like Spring & Hibernate is absolutely helpful but you can never be sure without tests.

Answer (score 1):

The `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty` annotation is deprecated now ([annotation type NotEmpty](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotEmpty.html)), I think this is a reason. Try to use the `javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty` annotation instead.

This issue has already been discussed here: [Hibernate @NotEmpty is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986091/hibernate-notempty-is-deprecated).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion.. But I already tried this.. the issue continues

Answer (score 0):

Use the annotation @SpringBootTest instead of @DataJpaTest, in order to load the full Spring context. And to test the constraint message you should use Validator.validate().
Change your test class as the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class StudentRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private StudentRepository studentRepository;

@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

private static Validator validator;

@BeforeClass
public static void setupValidatorInstance() {
    validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
}

@Test
public void testEmptyNameException() {
    thrown.expect(TransactionSystemException.class);

    this.studentRepository.save(new Student("","email@gmail.com"));
}

@Test
public void testEmptyNameExceptionMessage() {
    Student student = new Student("","email@gmail.com");

    Set<ConstraintViolation<Student>> violations = validator.validate(student);

    assertEquals(1 , violations.size());
    assertEquals("O campo nome do estudante é obrigatório", violations.iterator().next().getMessage());
}
}
```