# what is the new annotation which i can use instead of @NotBlank,@NotNull,@NotEmpty annotation because these annotation are deprecated

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, constraints

what is the new annotation which i can use instead of @NotBlank,@NotNull,@NotEmpty annotation? these annotation are deprecated

Answer (score 1):

These Hibernate annotations are deprecated in favor to standard Java annotations with the same names. They are in the package **javax.validation.constraints**.

Solution:

Please adjust your imports for the depracated annotations.

BTW: this explanation should be shown in the Javadoc of the deprecated modules. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to 
[Hibernate Validator 6.2.0.CR1 and 7.0.0.CR1 released](https://in.relation.to/2020/12/08/hibernate-validator-700-62-cr1-released/).

If you are using

- Hibernate Validator 7 or above, which support Jakarta EE
  -> Annotation from `jakarta.validation.constraints`.
- Hibernate Validator 6.x or below, which is still Java EE
  -> Annotation from `javax.validation.constraints`

Reference [Hibernate @NotEmpty is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986091/hibernate-notempty-is-deprecated)